# Updating a field through a dropdown in a php form

Tags: php, list, dropdown

I am coding in PHP - My SQL. I have a table named tbl_pers which has the personal details of the employees. I have another table tbl_group which has a number allotted to each type of group (a GpCode for every GpTitle). So in the tbl_pers table the number corresponding to the group defined in tbl_group is saved. When i try to update the tbl_pers using a form written in php, it updates fine, but if i update the form without making any changes it saves a null value in the tbl_pers table. I want it to save the value that was initially defined.
Please help

The code is given as under,

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
if(isset($_GET['urlvar_edit_pers'])){

    $get_id=$_GET['urlvar_edit_pers'];
    $get_pers="select * from tbl_pers where pNo='$get_id'";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($con, $get_pers);
    $i=0;

    $row_pers=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);

        $pNo=$row_pers['pNo'];
        $GpCode=$row_pers['GpCode'];
            $get_group="select * from tbl_group where GpCode='$GpCode'";
            $run_group=mysqli_query($con, $get_group);
            $row_group=mysqli_fetch_array($run_group);
            $GpTitle=$row_GpCode['GpTitle'];

        $i++;       
}
?>

<html>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <h3>Update Pers Record</h3>

    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="horizontal-form">
    <form action="" class="form-horizontal"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txt_pNo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Personal Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="txt_pNo" class="form-control1" id="txt_pNo" value="<?php echo $pNo;?>" placeholder="Personal Number"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8"><p class="help-block">Enter without any spaces.</p></div>
    </div>


    <!--Dropdown Dynamic List-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel_GpCode" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select name="sel_GpCode" id="sel_GpCode" value="<?php echo $GpCode;?> class="form-control1">
            <option><?php echo $GpTitle;?></option>
            <?php
                $get_GpCode="select * from tbl_group";
                $run_GpCode=mysqli_query($con, $get_GpCode);
                while($row_GpCode=mysqli_fetch_array($run_GpCode)){
                    $GpCode=$row_GpCode['GpCode'];
                    $GpTitle=$row_GpCode['GpTitle'];
                    echo"<option value='$GpCode'>$GpTitle</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>

<div class="bs-example" data-example-id="form-validation-states-with-icons">
<form>

        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <button class="btn-success btn" name="btn_update">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
</div>

</form>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_update'])){

    //getting the text data from the fields
    $update_id = $pNo;
    $GpCode=$_POST['sel_GpCode'];

$update_pers = "update tbl_pers set GpCode='$GpCode' where pNo='$update_id'";
$run_query = mysqli_query($con, $update_pers);

    if($run_query){
        echo"<script>alert('Person has been updated.')</script>";
        echo"<script>window.open('view_pers.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo"<script>alert('Could not add.')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: welcome to SO.  If you ever want to add relevant information to your question, do not make a comment.  Rather, you should edit your question so that all of the details are all in one place.  Please edit your question and delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use these two steps .

1. Rename $GpCode in while loop . let say $GpCodeloop.
2. Use selected in the option of drop down.
3. Apply the check on update query.

   `<option value='$GpCodeloop' <?php if($GpCode==$GpCodeloop){echo "selected='selected'";} ?>selected="selected">$GpTitle</option>`

   if(!empty($GpCode)){
       $update_pers = "update tbl_pers set GpCode='$GpCode' where pNo='$update_id'";
   $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $update_pers);
   }

Comment: Sorry Mahmood, the code didnt work. I am new to php, so I would request if you can give me the details.